# How to mask properly an input already filled from db?

Tags: jquery, input, mask, maskedinput

Here in Brazil, some phone numbers have 9 digits but default is 8, and because of that some developers have written some solutions for that, using jQuery Maskedinput plugin. I have this function:

```
$("#telephone").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
$("#telephone").blur(function(event) {
    if($(this).val().length == 15){
      $('#telephone').mask('(99) 99999-999?9');
    } else {
      $('#telephone').mask('(99) 9999-9999?9');
    }
});
```

What it does: if the phone number has 8 digits, it ignores a 9 digit and leaves the value as default format, which is (11) 0000-0000. If phone number has 9 digits, he takes the 1st digit from the 2nd block and put it on the end of 1st block, example: this (11) 9123-45678 becomes (11) 91234-5678, so the number 4 here was removed from last group and inserted at the end of 1st group so the 1st group has 5 digits like it should.

The problem is that when a input is already filled from db, the mask is not applied, it only works on "blur". Is there some crazy way to check if the input value has 9 digits and then apply the mask as it works on blur?

Additionally, just to have the possibility of re-use that code, I need to transform it into a function passing the elements ID as parameters (ideal could be just 1 ID or more). So, I've created the function below, but I'm not sure if I am calling it correctly:

```
function mask_phone(inputID) {
    $k(inputID).mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    $k(inputID).blur(function(event) {
        if($k(this).val().length == 15) {
            $k(inputID).mask('(99) 99999-999?9');
        } else {
            $k(inputID).mask('(99) 9999-9999?9');
        }
    });
}
```

Calling it...

```
mask_phone('#telephone, #fax');
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

This kind of question is so specific it's very unlikely to get an answer, however I had some free time an had a go at it. You can check a demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rar85Lr8/1/). It's not a very nice approach but it's the best I can do with that particular library.

```
var mask = function(ids) {
  var el = $(ids);
  $.each(el, function(i, elem) {
    //Get element
    var input = $(elem);

    //Store the original value (only numbers)
    var value = input.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

    //Choose mask according to length
    var mask = "(99) 9999-9999";
    if (value.length>10) {
        mask = "(99) 99999-9999"
    }

    //Trigger the mask    
    input.mask(mask);

    //Emulate the keypresses from original value
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      input.trigger({
        type: 'keypress',
        keyCode: value.charCodeAt(i)
      });
    }
    //Done
  });
}
```

While this may not solve your issue right away, I'm sure it will put you on the right track to figuring out what works best in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks man, I will take a look! BTW, yes, I have been through a lot of "unlikely-answered" questions, tell me about it... :( - Brazil is a pain for developers or even front-end guys.

Comment: Looks nice... Maybe there is something I don't get. Please enlight me, because this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/QpVVZE) works great for onload values... Like on `blur`. So I don't get why to use a more complex script. (I was about to anwer too...